# Does elementary receive Debian's security update?

Tags: updates, security

I was looking for a distribution to install a Linux system after a couple of years, and I really liked elementary OS!
But I was reading about it and it is based on Ubuntu, which is based on Debian.
And on the Debian page there is a bunch of security updates for applications, and I was wondering if elementary OS also has these updates.

Answer (score 6):

While Ubuntu is derived from Debian, Ubuntu has its own security team. This team is responsible for security updates to land in the Ubuntu software repositories.

As elementary OS uses the Ubuntu repositories, it's getting security updates from Ubuntu - While it's possible the Ubuntu security team adapts security updates from Debian, Debian security updates are not necessarily in Ubuntu and therefore not in elementary OS either. That does not mean Ubuntu & elementary OS are more insecure than Debian, but sometimes a software's code base is quite different between Ubuntu and Debian - A security update for Debian might not be needed for Ubuntu, for example.